# pass selected object to second viewcontroller and display in uilabel

Tags: core-data, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, segue, nsindexpath

I'm attempting to pass a selected item in a tableview to be displayed in a UILabel on a second viewcontroller. Currently I can segue to the second viewcontroller but nothing displays. I've also attempted to create an instance of the selected item for it to be used as reference in a predicate. The segue I have is:

```
            ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showResults"]); {

                ResultsVC *rvc = (ResultsVC *) [segue destinationViewController];
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.searchTV indexPathForSelectedRow];
                self.selectedItem =  [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                rvc.item = self.selectedItem;
                rvc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

and in cell for row at index path:

```
Item *item = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = item.itemName;
```

and in the second viewcontroller call the label to display the item:

```
        self.itemNameLabel.text = _selectedItem.itemName;
```

I have tried self.selectedItem.itemName and other iterations with no luck. 
What have I missed to get the UILabel to display data?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use NSUserDefaults to save the selected text and then retrieve it from the other view.
See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15721527/613858) to a similar question.